# How do we know that the set of sets that each contain real coefficient polynomials of distinct degrees is countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

If I have the set $V=\left \{S_{0},S_{1},S_{2},...\right \}$ where $S_{0}$ is the set of real constant polynomials, $S_{1}$ is the set of real polynomials with degree 1 and so on. How do we know that $V$ is countable?

Comment: Looks like you have exhibited a  "counting" , no?  $S_i\mapsto i$.

Comment: The map $\Bbb N\to V:n\mapsto S_n$ is a bijection.

Comment: You mean $V=\bigcup S_n$ ? Because there it is obviously countable.

Comment: Ahhhhhh ok thanks I see it now.

Comment: However, each $S_n$ itself is uncountable.

Answer (score -1):

It isn't. Just the set of polynomials over $\mathbb{R}$ of degree 0 is equinumerous with $\mathbb{R}$, so isn't countable; that being a subset of $\mathbb{R}[x]$ means the later one can't be countable either.